# Parallel computing in Linux - Efficiency

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a code with *parfor*s in a Matlab in Linux.

There are two problems.

1. The computer that has Linux is much stronger than the one I have Windows. (12 much stronger cores on the Linux computer compared to 4 on the Windows machine). However, it runs the job much much slower (261s to 457s).

Do you have any idea why this happens? Is there anything I had to do before running my job that decreased the performance? Or, is there anything that I need to modify in a code when runs in Linux compared to one that runs in Windows so that in runs more efficiently?

2. I feel that the parpool session closes every time a parfor loop ends. The four vertical lines on the bottom left of the screen, which shows parallel computing, turns blue and then green and so on in Linux. In Windows, they stay green until the whole job ends. Is this what I think or not?

This is the part of the code that takes the most of time and I use parfor

```
if some_condition
    parfor i = 1:s_m
        burg_i = single(loop_sm(i))*burgers(:,slip_sm(i));
        plane_i = planes(:,slip_sm(i));

        z1 = u_sm(:,i);
        x1 = [plane_i(2)*z1(3)-plane_i(3)*z1(2)
              plane_i(3)*z1(1)-plane_i(1)*z1(3)
              plane_i(1)*z1(2)-plane_i(2)*z1(1)];
        x1 = x1/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x1(2)^2+x1(3)^2);        
        y1 = [z1(2)*x1(3)-z1(3)*x1(2);z1(3)*x1(1)-z1(1)*x1(3);z1(1)*x1(2)-z1(2)*x1(1)];

        x0 = [1; 0; 0];
        y0 = [0; 1; 0];
        z0 = [0; 0; 1];

        Tseg = [x1'; y1'; z1']*[x0 y0 z0]; 
        bn = burg_i'*[x1 y1 z1];

        %% Segmented Dislocations Stress (misfits)
        for n = 1:s_th
            sig1 = zeros(3);

            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i),P2_sm(:,i),l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;

            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;

            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;
            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;

            sig_th11(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig1 * Tseg ;

            sig2 = zeros(3);

            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i),P2_sm(:,i),l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;

            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;

            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;
            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],P2_sm(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;

            sig_th21(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig2 * Tseg ;
        end
    end
    for i = 1 : s_th
        burg_i = burgers(:,slip_th(i));
        plane_i = planes(:,slip_th(i));

        z1 = u_th(:,i);
        x1 = [plane_i(2)*z1(3)-plane_i(3)*z1(2)
              plane_i(3)*z1(1)-plane_i(1)*z1(3)
              plane_i(1)*z1(2)-plane_i(2)*z1(1)];
        x1 = x1/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x1(2)^2+x1(3)^2);        
        y1 = [z1(2)*x1(3)-z1(3)*x1(2);z1(3)*x1(1)-z1(1)*x1(3);z1(1)*x1(2)-z1(2)*x1(1)];

        x0 = [1; 0; 0];
        y0 = [0; 1; 0];
        z0 = [0; 0; 1];

        Tseg = [x1'; y1'; z1']*[x0 y0 z0]; 
        bn = burg_i'*[x1 y1 z1];
        %% Segmented Dislocations Stress (Threads)
        for n = 1:s_th
            if n ~= i
                sig1 = zeros(3);

                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i),P2_sth(:,i),l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;

                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;

                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;
                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;

                sig_th12(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig1 * Tseg ;

                sig2 = zeros(3);

                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i),P2_sth(:,i),l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;

                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;0;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;0;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[0;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[0;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;

                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)-[box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[-box_length1;box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;
                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],P2_sth(:,i)+[box_length1;-box_length1;0],l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;

                sig_th22(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig2 * Tseg ;
            end
        end
    end

else
    parfor i = 1:s_m
        burg_i = single(loop_sm(i))*burgers(:,slip_sm(i));
        plane_i = planes(:,slip_sm(i));

        z1 = u_sm(:,i);
        x1 = [plane_i(2)*z1(3)-plane_i(3)*z1(2)
            plane_i(3)*z1(1)-plane_i(1)*z1(3)
            plane_i(1)*z1(2)-plane_i(2)*z1(1)];
        x1 = x1/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x1(2)^2+x1(3)^2);
        y1 = [z1(2)*x1(3)-z1(3)*x1(2);z1(3)*x1(1)-z1(1)*x1(3);z1(1)*x1(2)-z1(2)*x1(1)];

        x0 = [1; 0; 0];
        y0 = [0; 1; 0];
        z0 = [0; 0; 1];

        Tseg = [x1'; y1'; z1']*[x0 y0 z0];
        bn = burg_i'*[x1 y1 z1];

        %% Segmented Dislocations Stress (misfits)
        for n = 1:s_th
            sig1 = zeros(3);

            sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sm(:,i),P2_sm(:,i),l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig1;

            sig_th11(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig1 * Tseg ;

            sig2 = zeros(3);

            sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sm(:,i),P2_sm(:,i),l_sm(i),v,start_dis_sm(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                + sig2;

            sig_th21(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig2 * Tseg ;
        end
    end
    parfor i = 1 : s_th
        burg_i = burgers(:,slip_th(i));
        plane_i = planes(:,slip_th(i));

        z1 = u_th(:,i);
        x1 = [plane_i(2)*z1(3)-plane_i(3)*z1(2)
            plane_i(3)*z1(1)-plane_i(1)*z1(3)
            plane_i(1)*z1(2)-plane_i(2)*z1(1)];
        x1 = x1/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x1(2)^2+x1(3)^2);
        y1 = [z1(2)*x1(3)-z1(3)*x1(2);z1(3)*x1(1)-z1(1)*x1(3);z1(1)*x1(2)-z1(2)*x1(1)];

        x0 = [1; 0; 0];
        y0 = [0; 1; 0];
        z0 = [0; 0; 1];

        Tseg = [x1'; y1'; z1']*[x0 y0 z0];
        bn = burg_i'*[x1 y1 z1];
        %% Segmented Dislocations Stress (Threads)
        for n = 1:s_th
            if n ~= i
                sig1 = zeros(3);

                sig1 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid1(1,n),P_th_mid1(2,n),P_th_mid1(3,n), P1_sth(:,i),P2_sth(:,i),l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig1;

                sig_th12(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig1 * Tseg ;

                sig2 = zeros(3);

                sig2 = segment_disloc6_6(P_th_mid2(1,n),P_th_mid2(2,n),P_th_mid2(3,n), P1_sth(:,i),P2_sth(:,i),l_sth(i),v,start_dis_th(i),bn,x1,y1,z1)...
                    + sig2;

                sig_th22(:,:,n,i) =  Tseg' * sig22 * Tseg ;
            end
        end
    end
end

        sig_th1 = s0 * (sum(sig_th11(:,:,1:s_th,:),4)+sum(sig_th12(:,:,1:s_th,:),4)) + sig_th_mis1;
        sig_th2 = s0 * (sum(sig_th21(:,:,1:s_th,:),4)+sum(sig_th22(:,:,1:s_th,:),4)) + sig_th_mis2;
```

and here is the function that is being called:

```
function S = segment_disloc6_6(xp,yp,zp, P1,P2,l,v,start,bn,x1,y1,z1)


if start == 1
    x = ([xp,yp,zp]-P1')*x1;
    y = ([xp,yp,zp]-P1')*y1;
    z = ([xp,yp,zp]-P1')*z1;
elseif start == 2
    x = ([xp,yp,zp]-P2')*x1;
    y = ([xp,yp,zp]-P2')*y1;
    z = ([xp,yp,zp]-P2')*z1;
else
    display('ERROR! Starting point is indicated as neither 1 nor 2!');
end


% T = [dot(x1,x0),dot(x1,y0),dot(x1,z0)
%      dot(y1,x0),dot(y1,y0),dot(y1,z0)
%      dot(z1,x0),dot(z1,y0),dot(z1,z0)];


% bx = bn(1); by = bn(2); bz = bn(3);

lambda = l-z;
R = sqrt(x^2+y^2+(lambda)^2); %l is disl. length
if R < 2.5500e-9
    R = 2.5500e-9; %Notice that this is 10*bval! if bval changed in the main code, this must also be changed!
end

sigxx2 = bn(1) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1+x^2/R^2+x^2/(R*(R+lambda))) + bn(2) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-x^2/R^2-x^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigyy2 = -bn(1) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-y^2/R^2-y^2/(R*(R+lambda))) - bn(2) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1+y^2/R^2+y^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigzz2 = bn(1) * (2*v*y/(R*(R+lambda)) + y*lambda/R^3) + bn(2) * (-2*v*x/(R*(R+lambda)) - x*lambda/R^3);
sigxy2 = -bn(1) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-y^2/R^2-y^2/(R*(R+lambda))) + bn(2) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-x^2/R^2-x^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigxz2 = -bn(1) * x*y/R^3 + bn(2) * (-v/R + x^2/R^3) + bn(3) * y*(1-v)/(R*(R+lambda));
sigyz2 = bn(2) * x*y/R^3 + bn(1) * (v/R - y^2/R^3) - bn(3) * x*(1-v)/(R*(R+lambda));

lambda = -z;
R = sqrt(x^2+y^2+(lambda)^2); %l is disl. length
if R < 2.5500e-9
    R = 2.5500e-9; %Notice that this is 10*bval! if bval changed in the main code, this must also be changed!
end

sigxx1 = bn(1) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1+x^2/R^2+x^2/(R*(R+lambda))) + bn(2) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-x^2/R^2-x^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigyy1 = -bn(1) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-y^2/R^2-y^2/(R*(R+lambda))) - bn(2) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1+y^2/R^2+y^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigzz1 = bn(1) * (2*v*y/(R*(R+lambda)) + y*lambda/R^3) + bn(2) * (-2*v*x/(R*(R+lambda)) - x*lambda/R^3);
sigxy1 = -bn(1) * (x/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-y^2/R^2-y^2/(R*(R+lambda))) + bn(2) * (y/(R*(R+lambda))) * (1-x^2/R^2-x^2/(R*(R+lambda)));
sigxz1 = -bn(1) * x*y/R^3 + bn(2) * (-v/R + x^2/R^3) + bn(3) * y*(1-v)/(R*(R+lambda));
sigyz1 = bn(2) * x*y/R^3 + bn(1) * (v/R - y^2/R^3) - bn(3) * x*(1-v)/(R*(R+lambda));


S = [sigxx2-sigxx1,sigxy2-sigxy1,sigxz2-sigxz1
    sigxy2-sigxy1,sigyy2-sigyy1,sigyz2-sigyz1
    sigxz2-sigxz1,sigyz2-sigyz1,sigzz2-sigzz1];

% S = S_l2 - S_l1;
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us some code, or at least a block structure of what is running.  Otherwise all we can do is speculate about the ways that the test is not what you think it is.

Comment: Did you open the parallel computing pool on the Linux machine using `parpool` or `matlabpool`?

Comment: @wallyk Done! I added my code

Comment: @Daniel Yes. However, even if I don't, Matlab apparently creates a pool automatically when it observes a parfor command in the code.

Comment: Did you try to limit the number of workers on the Linux machine to 4 (instead of 12) `parpool(4)` and run the code? How much time does it take to process? Maybe adding extra workers does not help to decrease the processing time for your task.